# Access current values of controls in page using PageMethods in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am having troubling accessing my controls  (AspxTextBox, AspxComboBox, AspxSpinEdit, AspxDateEdit) on a Page in a codeBehind method. I can see that my codebehind method is accessing from javascript. This is what I have done so far -

At my .aspx page

```
PageMethods.PG_MethodsCreateTrvHotels('AutoBooking');
```

And At my CodeBehind

```
[WebMethod(true)]
public static void PG_MethodsCreateTrvHotels(string reservationType)
{

   AutoRBooking AutoBok = (AutoRBooking )Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(AutoRBooking));
        AutoBok.CreateTrvHotels(reservationType);

}


private void CreateTrvHotels(string reservationType)
{

    ///////// Some Logic Code//////////////////

       ** Get .aspx control Values here for further processing**

       /////////////Some Logic code Based on AspxTextBox, AspxComboBox, AspxSpinEdit, AspxDateEdit values////////////////////
 }
```

I have used the Page.FindControl() but it is raising null everytime.

Any code sample will be very helpful.

Thanks and Regards,
Naser Javed

Comment: You can't________

Comment: then what can be the best possible way to handle my situation - I have tried using AspxCallBacks. The issue is that my callbacks become nested then - From the activated aspxCallBack I tried to call the JavaScript function that again activates a 2nd callback (AspxCallback2.PerformCallback()) - This 2nd Callback never raises - At Code behind when the first Callback is running i have this -ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "ConfirmCode", "ActivateConfirmCode2Callbacks();", true); This never seems to trigger the 2nd callback. What could be an alt.solution then?

Comment: use jquery.ajax

Comment: can u please tell me shortly the flow i must follow to achieve my requirement - PageMethods was optional in the first place, but i felt it was a solution because i can simply call the -ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "ConfirmCode", "ActivateConfirmCode2Callbacks();", true); inside a code behind method. But when i raise my first Callback and apply the script for my 2ndCallBack activation. The 2nd one doesn't execute. I think i cannot register the ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript because already anaspx callbaclk is running.